# Order list of objects by a list of ids

Tags: c#, linq

So, I have a list of objects (let's say there are 20) and they have an id. Then I have another list (which is ordered correctly).
I had this linq to sort the object list by the id list:

```
var outcomeIds = outcomeRequestModels
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
  .Select(m => m.Id)
  .ToList();

groupResponseModel.Outcomes = groupOutcomes
  .OrderBy(m => outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id))
  .ToList();
```

Now, this "would" work, but the problem is the **outcomeIds** only has a selection of ids in it. I would have thought that `indexOf` would return `-1` for any id that was not found and it would be put under the matched ids. Instead they appear first in the list.
How can I modify my code to get the matching ids at the top and the rest at the bottom. I can't do a reverse, because it would mean that the order of the matching ids would be in reverse too.

Comment: Could you give a example list of input, and expected output ? Would make your case much clearer IMHO.

Comment: A [mcve] (which included @Pac0's suggestion) would be awesome.

Comment: m=>(uint)outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id) probably will solve the problem. But actually your LINQ with 2-times materialization is not very good, only if there are really 20 objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to order by the result of `IndexOf`, but to have the -1 values go to the end instead of the start. In that case, you could just process the value of the `IndexOf` to, say, `int.MaxValue` so it'll go at the end.

I've *tidied up* your code a bit to make it more readable - only the `OrderBy` is different to your original code.

```
var outcomeIds = outcomeRequestModels
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
    .Select(m => m.Id)
    .ToList();

groupResponseModel.Outcomes = groupOutcomes
    .Select(m => Tuple.Create(m, outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id))
    .OrderBy(m => outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id) == -1 ? int.MaxValue : outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id))
    .ToList();
```

---

Or, if you don't want to call `IndexOf` multiple times, you could extract the conditional statement into a method:

```
var outcomeIds = outcomeRequestModels
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
    .Select(m => m.Id)
    .ToList();

groupResponseModel.Outcomes = groupOutcomes
    .Select(m => Tuple.Create(m, outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id))
    .OrderBy(m => orderByKeySelector(outcomeIds(m.Id)))
    .ToList();
```

where `orderByKeySelector` is

```
private static int orderByKeySelector<T>(List<T> source, T value)
{
    var indexOfValue = source.IndexOf(value);
    return indexOfValue == -1 ? int.MaxValue : indexOfValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var outcomeIds = outcomeRequestModels
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
  .Select(m => m.Id)
  .ToList();

groupResponseModel.Outcomes = groupOutcomes
  .OrderBy(m => outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id) != -1
     ? outcomeIds.IndexOf(m.Id) 
     : outcomeIds.Max())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer keeping it simple:

```
var outcomeList;
var unorderedList;

//check all elements of the ordered list in order
foreach(var item in orderedList) 
{
    //if your unordered list has this item
    if(unorderedList.Any(item))
    {
        //add this item to the final list
        outcomeList.Add(item);
        //and remove it from unordered
        unorderedList.Remove(item);
    }
}

//at this point, you added all your matching entities in order, the rest is the remainder:

outcomeList.AddRange(unorderedList);
```

You can even turn this into an extension method for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using *mapping* (say, `id == 5` corresponds to `0`, `id = 123` to `1` etc.) with a help of dictionary? It will be efficient in case of long lists:

```
var order = outcomeRequestModels
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
  .Select((m, index) => new {
     id = m.id,
     index = index }) 
  .ToDictionary(item => item.id,      // id
                item => item.index);  // corresponding index
```

Now let's sort the 2nd list:

```
groupResponseModel.Outcomes = groupOutcomes
  .OrderBy(m => order.TryGetValue(m.Id, out var order) 
     ? order          // if we have corresponding index, use it   
     : int.MaxValue)  // otherwise, put the item at the bottom
  .ToList();
```